# Inequality of real numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Is it true that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p\geq 1$ (or $p\geq 2)$ there exists a constant $C>0$ independent of $a,b$ of course, such that:

$(a-b)^{p-2} ab \leq C (a-b)^p$

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

No.

It it were true, this would hold in particular for all $b$ and all $a=b+1$.

But in this case, this would imply:
$$
b(b+1)\leq C 
$$
for all $b$, which is clearly wrong (let $b$ tend to $+\infty$).

Comment: @Charlie You're welcome. No if you want, you may upvote the answers you like and accept your prefered one.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general. Suppose $p\geq 1$ and $b=a+\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon>0$ will be chosen later. Then your inequality becomes $$(2C+1)ab\leq C(a^2+b^2)?\tag{1}$$ Substitute $b=a+\varepsilon$ in $(1)$ to get $$2Ca^2+2Ca\varepsilon+a^2+a\varepsilon\leq 2Ca\varepsilon+2Ca^2+\varepsilon^2\tag{2}$$ which simplifies into $$a^2+a\varepsilon\leq C\varepsilon^2\tag{3}$$ which is absurd taking $a$ large and $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is untrue.

$$ C \geq \frac{ (a - b)^{p} \cdot a b }{ (a - b)^{p + 2}} $$
where $a \neq b$.

or

$$ C \ge \frac{ab}{(a - b)^2} = \frac{ab}{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab}$$
which is easy to prove existent **dependent** on values of $a$ and $b$.

Alternatively, just use 2 different set of input values. If $C$ is not constant, then it is dependent on either $a$ or $b$ or both.

Comment: No, it isn't true.

Comment: @julien `untrue` it was meant to be.

Comment: Oh? well if $a\sim b$ it blows up unfortunately :(